# How can I schedule a DAG Airflow to run in 5 minutes from now for the first time?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Situation:

- Airflow 1.10.6
- it's November, 18th, 8.pm
- airflow.cfg.default_timezone = system (i.e. Europe/Berlin)

I want to run my new "sample_job" every day at 8.05 p.m.

My configuration:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(year=2019,month=11,day=18,hour=20,minute=0),
    'execution_timeout' : timedelta(hours=13)
}

dag = DAG(
'sample_job', 
 default_args=default_args, 
 catchup=False, 
 max_active_runs=1, 
 schedule_interval='05 20 * * *')
```

Now when I activate the job at 8.03 pm I realize that the job is executed immediately with yesterday's date as last_run date.

How do I have to change my settings so that the job is not executed before 8.05 pm?

Comment: Since you set the catchup=False I am not sure why it happens because you said you run it for the first time. Usually it happens when you pause your previous dag (same name dag_id) and continue to where you last pause it. have you restart your scheduler ?

Comment: Check out this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1156

Comment: Did you change the `start_date` or `schedule_interval` parameter _after_ you scheduled the DAG script in Airflow?

Answer (score 0):

The very first DAG run is triggered soon after `start_date + schedule_interval` [[1](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html)]. Your schedule interval is ***one day*** and you want the first DAG run to start after 2019-11-***18*** 20:05, so your `start_date` should be 2019-11-***17*** 20:05.

As to why a DAG run is started as soon as you turns the DAG on, I suspect the reason for this is that you scheduled this DAG with a different `start_date` or `schedule_interval` before. If `start_date` or `schedule_interval` is changed it is recommended to change the `dag_id` too [[2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls)], because then a fresh set of metadata (and a new schedule) is created for the renamed DAG.